# Downloading Cmake through Powershell script

Tags: powershell, cmake

I am trying to write a Powershell script for downloading the cmake zip file and installing it on a computer. While I thought it would be a simple task I am running into some issues with connecting to the cmake website. Here is my code:

```powershell
$url = "https://cmake.org/files/v3.13/cmake-3.13.0-rc1-win64-x64.zip"
$output = "E:\test.zip"
$client = new-object System.Net.WebClient 
$client.DownloadFile($url,$output)
```

When I run it, I get an error:

```powershell
System.Management.Automation.MethodInvocationException: Exception calling "DownloadFile" with "2" argument(s): "The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send." ---> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send. ---> System.IO.IOException: Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream.
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ForceAuthentication(Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Net.TlsStream.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult result)
   at System.Net.TlsStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeaders(Boolean async)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadFile(Uri address, String fileName)
   at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object , Object , Object )
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Management.Automation.ExceptionHandlingOps.ConvertToMethodInvocationException(Exception exception, Type typeToThrow, String methodName, Int32 numArgs, MemberInfo memberInfo)
   at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object , Object , Object )
   at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.DynamicInstruction`4.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
```

It looks like there is something with the cmake website that is closing the transport stream and preventing me from downloading the file. What should I do? How can I get around this?

Comment: Which version of PowerShell? `$PSVersionTable.PSVersion`

Comment: Look into start-bitstransfer

Comment: @lit I am using Powershell v5 (5.1.17134.228)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the following lines preceding your code:

```
# Avoid errors with Invoke-WebRequest:
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol -bor [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
```

Comment: This solution worked. Mind explaining a bit deeper what was wrong and how it fixed it?